# How do I get rid of tomcat default session id?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, cookies

I am using tomcat 6.0.14, which does not support configuration for cookies.

So I have couple of pages in my app:

```
app.com/login.jsp<br>
app.com/dasboard.htm
```

The problem is that when user is at `login.jsp`, I see `JSESSIONID` as a cookie. I want to see session cookies only post logon when I am at dashboard - How do I make this happen?

Comment: JSESSIONID is by default added by browser to every request and not specific to Tomcat server

Comment: @RahulAgrawal: not true. Firstly, it's added by the server, not by the browser. Secondly - only if HTTP session was requested on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default every JSP creates new HTTP session (which is not the case for user servlets). Add this on top of your `login.jsp` to avoid eager session creation:

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

Comment: sometimes simplest of things escape your mind! :) I can't believe I was looking for an answer, already knowing it - thanks, Tomasz